# Как сделать плавный переход?

Tags: css

[image: Можно ли при помощи CSS сделать такой плавный переход с красного на черный фон?]

Можно ли при помощи CSS сделать такой плавный переход с красного на черный фон? Или с помощью чего и как это можно сделать?

Comment: Один раз после загрузки. Именно не понимаю как такой сильный изгиб можно сделать, что на красном фоне, что на черном. Думал мб border-radius, но вроде бы как нет.

Comment: Попробуйте этот изгиб сунуть в `<li><img тут ваш изгиб> </li>`. Я думаю, так тоже можно)

Answer (score 4):

На примере `border-radius`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; //необязательно
}

.perehod {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.perehod .red {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C5453A, #A31716);
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  border-radius: 0px 90px 0px 0px / 0px 100% 0px 0px;
}

.perehod .black {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #444444, #202020);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="perehod">
  <div class="black">
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Правая страна не та, и где тут `svg`

Comment: ой перепутал...

Answer (score 2):

Средствами css такое сделать реально, но неэффективно, легче просто Вставить изображение png/svg изгиба после элементов меню, задать css левой и правой части меню (2 градиента)

Comment: А если ширина контейнера не фиксировано?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan svg тебе в помощь.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan сначала градиент, потом изображение изгиба, потом еще один градиент. Сделай изгиб отдельным блоком.

Comment: А зачем все это мне в комментариях говорите? а не в ответе напишите?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan а не знаю :) Ты понял что я хотел донести?

Comment: твои последние комментарии как то противоречат твоему ответку

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan они дополняют и поясняют, но не противоречат. Вставить изображение изгиба после элементов меню, задать css левой и правой части меню (2 градиента).

Comment: еще раз говорю все это надо в ответе написать, а не так что бы часами поболтать в комментариях потом понять вашу мысль

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать svg/png картинки как бэкграунд псевдоэлемента, который расположить на месте стыка. Вставлять в HTML не рекомендуется, так как там должны быть "значущие" элементы...

Можно на CSS - используйте псевдоэлементы и border-radius. Пример:

```css
div {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height: 20px;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.black {
  background: black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  position: relative;
}
.black::before,.black::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width:20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -18px;
  top: 0px;
}
.black::before {
  background: black;
}
.black::after {
  background: red;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
```